# How to populate a map[string] interface{} when my value is a struct type?

Tags: go

I am wanting to build a JSON equivalent of the `PurchaseOrder` struct below:

```
type PurchaseOrder struct {
    State      string
    FsmName    string
    Supplier   string
    Receiver   string
    TradeItems map[string]PRTradeItem
}

type PRTradeItem struct {
    Quantity float64 `json:"quantity"`
    Supplier string  `json:"supplier"`
    Receiver string  `json:"receiver"`

    PricePerUnit float64 `json:"pricePerUnit"`
}
```

In order to do so, I did the following:

```
po := make(map[string]interface{})
po["Sender"] = "org2"
po["Receiver"] = "org1"
po["TradeItems"] = make(map[string]PRTradeItem)
po["TradeItems"]["sku1"] = PRTradeItem{Quantity: 100, Supplier: "org2", Receiver: "org1", PricePerUnit: 10.5}
poAsBytes, _ := JSON.Marshal(po)
```

The error that I get is:

> invalid operation: po["TradeItems"]["sku1"] (type interface {} does not support indexing).

After looking around a bit, I added the following lines to the code and it worked.

```
internalMap, ok := po["TradeItems"].(map[string]PRTradeItem)
if !ok{

    panic("why???")
}
if ok{  
    internalMap["sku1"] = PRTradeItem{Quantity:100,Supplier:"org2", Receiver:"org1", PricePerUnit:10.5}
}
```

I don't quite understand what this line means

```
internalMap, ok := po["TradeItems"].(map[string]PRTradeItem)
```

Can someone please explain?

Comment: It's a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions). `v.(T)` asserts that the value `v` is of type `T`. So `po["TradeItems"].(map[string]PRTradeItem)` asserts that the value associated with the `"TradeItems"` key in map `po` is of type `map[string]PRTradeItem`.

Comment: Sure, but why is that needed? I know the type of `po["TradeItems"]` . Please explain in-depth. Why should I assert?

Comment: Why don't you just marshal your struct directly? Why bother with the map?

Comment: You should type assert, because that's the only way to get to the underlying data type of an interface.

Comment: Because Go is a statically typed language and you defined `po`'s value type as `interface{}` so the result of `po[somekey]` will always be a value of type `interface{}`.

Answer (score 6):

> I am wanting to build a JSON equivalent of the PurchaseOrder struct below:
>
> ```
> type PurchaseOrder struct {
>     State      string
>     FsmName    string
>     Supplier   string
>     Receiver   string
>     TradeItems map[string]PRTradeItem
> }
> ```

The easiest way is:

```
po := PurchaseOrder{
    State:      "paid",
    Supplier:   "Acme, Inc.",
    TradeItems: map[string]PRTradeItem{
        "sku1": PRTradeItem{Quantity: 100, Supplier: "org2", ... },
    },
}
poAsBytes, err := json.Marshal(po)
```

Forget about your `po := make(map[string]interface{})` and manual manipulation of the map.

If you need to control the JSON keys in your `PurchaseOrder` object, add the appropriate `json` tags, as you did for the `PRTradeItem` definition.

Answer (score 3):

> I know the type of `po["TradeItems"]`. Please explain in-depth. Why should I assert?

You do, but the compiler doesn't. Your `po` has type `map[string]interface{}`. So `po["TradeItems"]` in `po["TradeItems"]["sku1"]` returns an object of type `interface{}`, which you can't do anything useful with (not without reflection or type-assertions).

Hence the need to hint the compiler with that type assertion.